# How to prevent squizzle with type value passed in variable

Tags: typescript

f(c) below has squizzle which is fine. But I don't want them for f(va), is it possible somehow ?

```
    type TParam = 'a' | 'b';
    function f(param: TParam) {
      alert(param);
    }

    f('a');
    f('b');
    f('c');
    let va = 'a';
    f(va);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type for `va` here is `string` (which is usually what you want). But you can narrow the type of `va` to match your signature:

```
let va: 'a' = 'a';
f(va)
```